# Vagrant VMware Utility driver

Tags: vagrant, vmware, hashicorp

First of all I'm sorry if someone already did this question, in this case please paste the link here because I didn't find anything.
I'm learning vagrant, using virtualbox i don't have problem in running VM, but if I would like to use VMware as provider. I encounter this message and I can't find a way to get out of this.
I think everything is well configured but obviously something is wrong.

When I launch `vagrant up --provider=vmware_desktop`, I have this error message:

```
Vagrant encountered an unexpected communications error with the
Vagrant VMware Utility driver. Please try to run the command
again. If this error persists, please contact support@hashicorp.com
```

I'm currently using Fedora 35

```
Operating System: Fedora Linux 35 (Workstation Edition)
          Kernel: Linux 5.17.5-200.fc35.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: did u download the VMWare utility driver ? https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/vmware/vagrant-vmware-utility

Comment: Everything done, even now I make another time everything to be sure, and I don't encounter problem in this phase

Comment: I confirm that I also applied well the certificate and license

Comment: can you add in your question the Vagrantfile, check `service.log` (on Mac its /Library/Application Support/vagrant-vmware-utility/service.log) to make sure service is running

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac M1

Answer (score 3):

I have followed this thread:

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/issues/22

and someone had prepared a nice gist -- which I copied below just in case the gist link wasn't anymore.

> My issue was mainly the Vagrant 2.2.19 which somehow was not ok with VMWare. 2.2.18 worked fine. Just make sure you follow the above gist step by step.

https://gist.github.com/sbailliez/f22db6434ac84eccb6d3c8833c85ad92

My issue was mainly the Vagrant 2.2.19 which somehow was not ok with VMWare. 2.2.18 worked fine. Just make sure you follow the above gist step by step.

## Vagrant and VMWare Tech Preview on Apple M1 Pro

This document summarizes notes taken while to make the VMWare Tech preview work on Apple M1 Pro, it originated
from discussions in https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/issues/22

### Installing Rosetta

First install Rosetta if not already done, this is needed to run x86 code:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

### Installing Vagrant

Install Vagrant via brew or install it manually. Note that I use [2.2.18](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.18/vagrant_2.2.18_x86_64.dmg) as 2.2.19 did not work for me. (YMMV)

```
brew install vagrant@2.2.18
```

### Installing VMWare Fusion Tech Preview

You will need to create an account on vmware as it needs user and key information that are user specific.
The registration process is kinda convoluted. Be careful about passwords as the password needs to be less than 20 characters and there are no error messages for this.

You can download the tech preview via the [download page](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/downloads/get-download?downloadGroup=FUS-PUBTP-2021H1).

Once this is installed you will *NEED* to create a symlink as the vagrant vmware utility etc.. assumes that vmware is installed in a specific directory and the tech preview is installed in a different one.

```
ln -s /Applications/VMWare\ Fusion\ Tech\ Preview.app /Applications/VMWare\ Fusion.app
```

### Installing Vagrant VMWare provider

It requires two steps. This is detailed in the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/vmware/installation) but follow the steps below:

First go to [Vagrant vmware Utility](https://www.vagrantup.com/vmware/downloads) and download the binary and install it. It says x86_64 but it is fine.

The direct link is:

```
https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant-vmware-utility/1.0.21/vagrant-vmware-utility_1.0.21_x86_64.dmg
```

It needs to be version 1.0.21

Next install the provider:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop
```

### Create a Vagrant file

Create a file `Vagrantfile`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "spox/ubuntu-arm"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"
end
```

### Run vagrant

```
vagrant up
```

and then

```
vagrant ssh
```

Hopefully this should work and you should find yourself with mostly everything working.

### Troubleshooting

I have observed various issues that makes the whole experience unstable or creating conflicts.

#### vagrant 2.2.19 is broken

I have had issues trying to run vagrant 2.2.19. Use [2.2.18](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.18/vagrant_2.2.18_x86_64.dmg)

#### vagrant-vmware provider forwarded ports bound

If you declare forwarding port on your box, for some reasons the provider persists them and keeps it bound in LISTEN state even after you do a `vagrant halt`.

You can check this using something like:

```bash
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep 'vagrant-v'
```

You can see the ports are stored in:

```bash
cat /opt/vagrant-vmware-desktop/settings/portforwarding.json
```

To stop the provider use:

```bash
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vagrant.vagrant-vmware-utility.plist
```

To start it again, use `load` instead of `unload`.

#### nfs exports conflicts

If your vagrant box uses nfs, it seems to pollute the  `/etc/exports` file with duplicate or stale entries over time which will cause vagrant to get angry at you at some point. You may need to prune the entries. It seems related to [vagrant#11418](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11418)

Comment: Amir jan, I have tried everything written in this answer, but none of them worked properly on M2.

Comment: I have not tried any of the above on M2 unfortunately but only M1 pro. To the best of my knowledge, recently Virtual Box has released a developer preview version (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) that works with Mac M1 and M2. That might be a more reliable solution since with virtual box you might be able to create your own boxes. So you might want to use virtual box as a provider instead. Again I have not tried this one myself either, just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue you had with the architecture compatibility while trying to set up VM on my Mac M1. Found my solution in this [GitHub thread](https://gist.github.com/sbailliez/f22db6434ac84eccb6d3c8833c85ad92)

I just added this lines to the Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provider :vmware_desktop do |v|
        v.vmx["ethernet0.pcislotnumber"] = "160"
end
```

Comment: Hi, It would be helpful if someone can also point where the Vagrantfile lives

Comment: @Fact I don't know if you have found the answer to this. The Vagrant file can be found in your home directory from your terminal just type 
`ls -a` then you should see Vagrantfile in the list if you have a VM installed, then to open with vim or vi editor `vi Vagrantfile`, make your edits and save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same error and then went with another box work for me.
Initially, I was trying with bento/ubuntu-22.04 box, but it was showing the same error, then tried with bento/ubuntu-20.04 worked for me.